# Add fade-in or fade-out on the addclass / removeclass event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I created an `addclass` and `removeclass` event :

```
$(".myclass").click(function(){
   $(".hiding").removeClass("hiding");
   $(this).addClass("hiding");
});
```

using the following CSS :

```
#wrapper a.hiding {
   display: none; 
}
```

and the HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a class="myclass" href="#2">
        <img src="example.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

I can't seem to find a way to add a `fade-in` action when `addclass` is triggered. I would also like to add a `fade-out` when `removeClass` is triggered.

I have tried the following CSS without success:

```
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Is there a better way through Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you try [this](http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/)

edit: I realized just now using fadeIn() is better, try this:

```
$(".myclass").click(function(){
   $(".hiding").fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $(".hiding").removeClass("oldStuffHere");
       $(this).addClass("newStuffHere");
       $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
           // Animation complete
            });
      });

});
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't allow onclick function, and I don't want an automatic slideshow

Comment: does the fadeIn() fadeOut() function fits?