# Adding slide animation in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

How can I add fade animation to my contact form with validation? I don't want use CSS transition. I'm just not sure where to put fadeIn in following code:

```
$('#message').focusout(function() {
    if (!$(this).val())
        $(this).addClass('error').parent().find('mark').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
    else
        $(this).removeClass('error').parent().find('mark').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
});
```

Comment: When do you want it to fade in?

Comment: When "error" class is adding / removing.

Comment: Do you want to fade out the form if validation completed and otherwise leave it? If you just want to fade out while it is adding the class you'll get a jumpy animation.

Comment: All your code is doing is added and removing classes. There's nothing really to fadeIn. Now if you were adding a background or something via jQuery you could animate it, but you can't really animate a class being added.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. I want to add fade animation, because "error" class makes field (input) highlighted.

Comment: That's still not clear, please tell us what you want to fade, when you want to fade, and what type of fade (in/out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to achieve fade in animation , for validating an input field , and also you need to validate when the user moves out of focus

your approach is correct

You can follow this SO posting here [fadein fadeout on add or remove class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875542/add-fade-in-or-fade-out-on-the-addclass-removeclass-event)

I tested the Jsfiddle you posted in the comment , focusout wont work in this scenario , you have to use onblur

and also you cant use jquery addclsss here you have to use [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) [addClass](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://jqueryui.com/removeClass/) API's to achive animation during change of classes

Off course there some hacks using which you could achive this with out Jquery UI , but still this is the tested approach and easy to achieve .

Comment: Hm I've still issues with it. Maybe because in my code there's if / else but when I do this same as in sample script doesn't work. I'm such begginer.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle by putting your html and css so that I can post javascript others too may help you

Comment: Please use Jquery UI add class as mentioned above in my posting, normal animate and add class is not working in your scenario .